# Display Syncfusion Chart TrackBall at top of Chart

Tags: syncfusion, syncfusion-chart

We want to display our TrackBall label at the top of the Graph. We do not want to `GroupAllPoints` but that appears to be the only way to get the label to appear at the top of the graph.

When we do set `LabelDisplayMode="GroupAllPoints"` the label ignores the `LabelTemplate` we have set on the `LineSeries`. I assume that is because `GroupAllPoints` covers multiple Series.

1. How do set LabelDisplayMode to NearestPoint but display that label
   at the top of the graph?
2. Alternatively how do I create a Template that does get picked up
   when GroupAllPoints  is set. Despite us only having a single point
   to display in the TackBall. We'd only be doing this if there was no other way to get the trackball to display at the top of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirement we have prepared a sample for your reference. In which we have achieved your requirement using the "annotation" property in the chart. Please find the below sample, code snippet, and screenshot.

**Sample:** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/AnnotationSample-1842581013.zip

**Code Snippet:**

```
<ejs-chart id="lineContainer" >
  // add additional code here
  <e-chart-annotations>
     <e-chart-annotation Content="<div id=lineContainer_tooltip></div>" X="90%" Y="1%" CoordinateUnits='@Syncfusion.EJ2.Charts.Units.Pixel' region="Series"></e-chart-annotation>    
    </e-chart-annotations>
```

Screenshot:
[image: AnnotationSample]